# reordering of columns data in mysql / oracle sever

Tags: database, oracle

I have created the below table first,

```
create table original( a integer, b varchar(5), c integer);
```

using CTAS, I will rearrange the column order of above table.

My question is, there is dependency of triggers and constraints and default of table attributes.

How can I achieve this??

Comment: Can you clarify what you are actually trying to do here?

Comment: just want to reorder the columns . how can i?

Comment: You mean you want to be `a integer, c integer, b varchar(5)` like that after creating the table? edit your post and include the details as how your end result should look like.

Comment: exactly like that . but there is dependency of constraints how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

Disable the contstraints

```
CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE AS
SELECT A, C, B
FROM ORIGINAL;
```

Drop the original table

Rename newtable to original.

Reenable the constraints